# passing instance name as string in a function

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am creating an Adobe Air Desktop project which has many MovieClips in the MainTimeline (RadioSel, CarMC1, CarMC2, CarMC3, etc).
When you click on any of `CarMC`  it shows `RadioSel` (another movieclip)

```
function showRadio(event: MouseEvent) {
    RadioSel.visible = true;
    RadioSel.instance = event.currentTarget.name;
    trace (RadioSel.instance);
}
```

The `CarMC` are MovieClips that have many frames. Each one shows a different shape which depends on `RadioSel` choice.  The `RadioSel` is a MovieClip that has multiple radio buttons, each of which changes `CarMC` to a different shape, and a var called `instance` which carries the clicked `CarMC` instance as string.

I created a function inside the `RadioSel` (called when radiobuttongroup changes) which changes the clicked `CarMC` to a specified frame and hides the `RadioSel`.

```
function chooseCar(CarInstance: String, frame: Number) {
    this["Object(root)."+CarInstance].gotoAndStop(frame);
    this.visible = false;
    //trace(event.target)
}
```

When I change `RadioSel` choice, I call this...

```
chooseCar(instance, frameNo)
```

... where `instance` is the name of the `CarMC`, and `frameNo` is a number defined by the radio button clicked, however, I get an error every time I call the function. I believe the error is in this part:

```
this["Object(root)."+CarInstance].gotoAndStop(frame);
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please include the error you're receiving.  You can know exactly what line it's occurring on if you toggle "Permit Debugging" and compile in *Debug Mode* (https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing an instance (movieclip) but the instance name (string). You should just pass the car instance (movieClip) to make things easier - then you don't care where your cars are and how to access them:

```
function showRadio(event: MouseEvent) 
{
    RadioSel.visible = true;
    // I assume the currentTarget is your car you've clicked on
    // pass the movieclip instance to the radiosel and not just the name
    RadioSel.instance = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;
    trace (RadioSel.instance.name);
}
```

In your RadioSel:

```
public var instance:MovieClip;

// no need to pass the instance here as it is saved in the instance property anyway
function chooseCar(frame: Number) 
{
    instance.gotoAndStop(frame);
    this.visible = false;
}
```